# Clojure evaluate lazy sequence

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

Hi I need to return string from `stringify` function, but currently I'm getting lazy seq. Can't wrap my head how to evaluate lazy seq.

So what I need is to have chain call like this:
`(println "Formated: " (fmt (stringify m)))`

```
(defn stringify [m]
    "Construct string expression"
    (let [res (reduce-kv (fn [acc k v]
                    (let [s (str/join "" [v (name k)])]
                      (if (pos? v)
                        (if (empty? acc)
                          (concat acc ["+" s])
                          (concat acc s))
                        (concat acc s))
                      ))

          "" m)]
      res))

(defn fmt [s]
    "Apply formating rules"
    (-> s
        (.replaceAll "([+-])" " $1 ")
        (println)))
```

Comment: I would consider using `clojure.string/replace` instead of Java interop and `.replaceAll`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concat` operates on `seq`s, not strings. It works on strings, but treats them as sequences of characters. It [returns a lazy seq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/concat), which you can realize into a string with `clojure.string/join`.

Replacing the last statement `res` in your stringify function with `(clojure.string/join "" res)` should do the trick. However, you could build a string with `reduce-kv` from the get-go, using `join` instead of `concat`. You can reduce into anything, not just collections/seqs.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with strings, just use `str` for concatenation:

```
(concat acc s))         => (str acc s)
(concat acc ["+" s])    => (apply str [acc "+" s])  ; note moved `[`
```

examples:

```
=> (str "abc" "def")
"abcdef"

=> (apply str ["abc"  "de" "fgh"] )
"abcdefgh"

=> (clojure.string/join ["abc"  "de" "fgh"] )  ; like `(apply str...)`
```